# 25% of all people are qualified for Job A. If I pick 6 random applicants, how likely are the first 2 to be qualified?

Tags: probability

Would I require Bayes' theorem for this question? I tried using permutations and combinations but it didn't work.

Comment: Am I missing something or is it simply $0.25*0.25$?

Comment: You seem to be assuming applicants are typical of "all people".  Usually this is not correct for jobs requiring qualifications

Comment: @RayDansh  Well I suppose theoretically it would be $0.25*\frac {0.25\times\text{world population} - 1}{\text{world population}-1}$... but .... yeah....

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure how the 6 people are supposed to play into the equation, that bit is a tad unclear.

Having said that, if you have a finite number of people that you can choose from (call it $n$), then the odds of drawing two qualified people back to back is:

$$\frac{\frac{n}{4}}{n}\times\frac{\frac{n}{4}-1}{n-1}$$

Say we had 8 people. Then two of them would be qualified, so:

$$\frac{2}{8}\times\frac{1}{7}=\frac{2}{56}$$

Note that as $n\rightarrow\infty$, the probability of this event gets closer to Ray’s commented answer of $\frac{1}{16}$.

Now if your question is asking “given that I’ve already picked 6 people from a distribution where 25% of them are qualified, what is the probability that the first two I ‘pick’ (say to interview or something) consecutively are qualified?”, then please clarify because that’s a different question.